# Zend layout - how to make a menu item selected?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this layout file called menuAdmin. 
I wish to, each time a given controller and a given action is active, to show the "li" element with a specific class.

So, I have the following on my menuAdmin.php :

```
<li <?php echo ($this->controller == "d" && $this->action == "a") ? "class='selectedMenuItem'" : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array("controller"=>"d","action"=>"a.d"))?>">Aaaa Dddd</a></li>
```

I get nothing with this, and if I dump:
`var_dump($this->controller);` and `var_dump($this->action);` I get NULL NULL

- So I believe Zend don't trigger those at that point.

*Question*:
How can I accomplish such a task? Should I follow this path? If so, how will my menuAdmin layout know about what controller and action is in place?

**Update:**
menuAdmin.php is a layout file, inside Layouts folder on Zend structure. 
This is a large application and the structure in place is already like this - using layout files as menus where this is just one of them.

So $this->controller and $this->action only work inside the controller, OR if I explicitly pass it to the view. On this case, however, I would like to call it on the layout. Why there? Because by doing so, I can make one change and allow that change to be replicated all over the views that use this layout.

Regarding the above clarifications, could your answers change ?

**Update 2:**
I don't know if this is relevant or not but, all this menuadmin layout is called from a main layout file "layouts/main.php" and there we have: `<?php echo $this->render("menuadmin.php"); ?>`

Thanks again

Comment: Why don't you want to use Zend_Navigation? If you really must access the request object in your layout (see Jake's answer) use `$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();`

Comment: It's not that I don't want. Is more, that I don't have the knowledge to fully understand it and plus, to understand it in a way that I can put it on this already existing structure. :( - I will update my question again and, at the same time, try out this code. K. Regards.

Comment: @Thanks Phil for your additional comment. I got it working. I sure need to learn how to proper structure all this application stuff, but clients should also learn to give us time to elaborate this... oh well. :) Cheers and thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what `menuAdmin.php` is you can get the controller and action in a variety of ways.

If your file is a controller you can do one of the following, they all do the same thing

```
 $controller = $this->getRequest()->controller;
 $controller = $this->getRequest()->getParam("controller");
 $controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Ideally you should use `Zend_Navigation` to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead use [Zend_Navigation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.html) as this is a built-in feature.

**Edit:** To answer your question about the null "controller" and "action" values; unless you have set these as view parameters from a controller or something else at the controller level (helper, plugin, etc), of course they will be empty.